# Datasheet help -- max pulse current for LED

Tags: led, datasheet

I am looking at this infrared LED: https://www.vishay.com/docs/84240/vsly5940.pdf

It seems to indicate a "Forward Current" of 100ma, a "Peak Forward Current" of 200ma, and a "Surge Forward Current" of 1A.

It doesn't seem to show the voltage required for the "Peak Forward Current", but it does give 2.9v for the 1A current.  It also gives a brightness value for this 1A "Surge" current.

Is it possible to operate this LED at 1A bursts for 100 us?

What is the maximum operating LED current for a very short burst?

Comment: Fig 3 in the datasheet shows the current vs. allowed pulse duration. Does that answer your question?

Comment: From the datasheet the diode equation appears as \$N=2\$, \$I_{_\text{SAT}}=18\:\text{fA}\$, and \$R_{_\text{S}}=1.25\:\Omega\$. So that:$$V_{_\text{D}}=2\:V_T\cdot\ln\left(1+\frac{I_{_\text{D}}}{18\:\text{fA}}\right)+I_{_\text{D}}\cdot 1.25\:\Omega$$You should be able to compute the LED voltage for any given current from that. And yes, it appears that if you wait for at least \$10\:\text{ms}\$ between pulses, then you may be able to manage \$100\:\mu\text{s}\$ pulses of \$1\:\text{A}\$. And \$1\:\text{A}\$ seems to be the absolute limit on the datasheet, regardless. Metal migration, probably.

Comment: @periblepsis Thanks for your response.  How did you determine these numbers?  I don't see 18 or 1.25 anywhere on the datasheet!

Comment: @Captain You didn't ask a question about how. So I didn't tell you. But I just looked at the curve, is all. There are details near the higher current end which give me the bulk resistance figure. That worked out to 1.25, rounded. There are other details to get the other numbers. I figured N was somewhere between 1.8 and 2.8, at first. But a slightly closer exam pushed me towards the lower end. So I picked 2 in round numbers. The saturation current then just falls out from there. Solving the equation directly for \$I_{_\text{D}}\$ is a little more involved. But you can just iterate, too.

Comment: @Captain If you want a procedure you can use in the future, you could just ask the question and I'll write something up for you. Your question here seems more focused upon worst case current operation of a specific LED. Which is too much different to embrace an answer about an entirely different topic.